# Haskell function that takes the list of values and a list of names as input and returns the common values used by all names in the values list

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to take an input, which I will call "Names", and use it to get an output, "Values" from a list in which "Value" is all lists that contain the given "Name". For example, if the list of lists is:

```
listOfLists = [("Name1", [Value1]), ("Name2", [Value2, Value3]), ("Name3", [Value1, Value2, Value3])]
```

and I give the input "Name 1, Name3" it will return "Value 1", as that is the value found in each.

Currently, what I have is this:

```
find_languages [] [] = []
find_languages ((x, y):xs) (courses) = filter ((x `elem` courses)((x, y):xs))
```

This is not working and I'm hoping for some tips. Some notes:

- There should be no recursion
- I can only use the Prelude Library
- I can use a function I have already written, `commons_all`, which returns all common values across a list of lists - this should make it easy but I'm not sure how to implement it.

```
commons_all :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [a]
commons_all [] = []
commons_all (x:xs) = foldl commons x xs
```

The expected form will be

```
find_languages :: (Eq a1, Eq a2) => [(a2, [a1])] -> [a2] -> [a1]
```

Currently, this isn't the form the function takes.

Answer (score 1):

What you desire is to extract just the relevant value lists from listOfLists and pass them to `commons_all`. This can be done in three steps.

1. obtain only the elements of listOfLists that have a name in courses. This can be done with `filter` and `elem` like your attempt so far, but you will not need to destructure the list argument, and instead will need to provide a function as the first argument to `filter`
2. Extract only the value parts of the filtered lists. This can be done with `map` and a function with the type `(a, b) -> b`
3. use commons_all on that result

Your final answer will likely look something like

```
find_languages list courses = commons_all $ map (something) $ filter (something) list
```

Answer (score 1):

First, let's find any tuples in `listOfLists` with one of the specified names. Our filter function first needs to extract the name using the `fst` function, then checks to see if it's an element of `names`.

```
Prelude> commonVals names lst = filter ((`elem` names) . fst) lst
Prelude> commonVals ["Name1", "Name3"] listOfLists
[("Name1",["Value1"]),("Name3",["Value1","Value2","Value3"])]
```

Having done that, we map `snd` to the results to get the values.

```
Prelude> commonVals names lst = map snd $ filter ((`elem` names) . fst) lst
Prelude> commonVals ["Name1", "Name3"] listOfLists
[["Value1"],["Value1","Value2","Value3"]]
```

Now that we have this, we just need to write an `intersect` function and fold it over the results.

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| commonVals names lst = foldl1 intersect $ map snd $ filter ((`elem` names) . fst) lst
Prelude|    where
Prelude|       intersect a b = filter (`elem` b) a
Prelude| :}
Prelude> commonVals ["Name1", "Name3"] listOfLists
["Value1"]
```

All of this can readily be accomplished with Prelude functions and no explicit recursion.